# Pandas .idxmin(axis=1) returns bad column name values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Value from pandas:

```
Index   Bra Obr Zal Uto Str Nah Tec Ryc Hla BestP_A BestP_Amin  BestP_minA
0       461 38  44  46  49  137 324 322 162 Bra     Obr         137.0
1       442 32  30  35  39  180 322 325 180 Bra     Obr         180.0
2       152 28  23  23  30  175 335 355 206 Bra     Obr         175.0
3       38  33  68  33  49  119 223 46  46  Zal     Obr         46.0
4       36  33  203 36  46  217 253 166 170 Zal     Obr         166.0
5       35  84  38  41  54  49  175 57  141 Obr     Nah         49.0
6       34  45  71  45  59  72  207 57  60  Zal     Obr         57.0
```

[Value from Pandas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zldZr.png)

I need return column name to column "BestP_Amin", Python return bad column name. Example value index 0:

```
BestP_A = Bra, Bra = 461, Nah = 137, Tec = 324, Ryc = 322, Hla = 162
```

code:

```py
if data.at[i,'BestP_A'] == 'Bra':
    data['BestP_Amin'] = data[['Bra','Nah','Tec','Ryc','Hla']].idxmin(axis=1)
```

Returned value `Obr`, where is problem?
Block code:

```
# nalezení nejleší pozice, přepočet podle výše atributů
for i in range(0,len(data.index)):
# nalezení pozice
    data['BestP_A'] = data[['Bra','Obr','Zal','Uto']].idxmax(axis=1)
#nalezení nejmenšího atributu
# VRACI CHYBNE HODNOTY
    if data.at[i,'BestP_A'] == 'Bra':
         data['BestP_Amin'] = data[['Bra','Nah','Tec','Ryc','Hla']].idxmin(axis=1)
    elif data.at[i,'BestP_A'] == 'Obr':
         data['BestP_Amin'] = data[['Obr','Nah','Tec','Ryc','Hla']].idxmin(axis=1)
    elif data.at[i,'BestP_A'] == 'Zal':
         data['BestP_Amin'] = data[['Zal','Nah','Tec','Ryc','Hla']].idxmin(axis=1)
    elif data.at[i,'BestP_A'] == 'Uto':
         data['BestP_Amin'] = data[['Uto','Nah','Tec','Ryc','Hla']].idxmin(axis=1)

    data.at[i,'BestP_minA'] = min(data.at[i,'Nah'],data.at[i,'Tec'],data.at[i,'Ryc'],data.at[i,'Hla'])
    data.at[i,'BestA_U'] = int(round(data.at[i,'BestA']*(data.at[i,'Ene']/100)*(1+(.25*data.at[i,'Sou']/100)+(.2*data.at[i,'Zku']/100)),0))
```

[Block code in python:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uukpg.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using a `for` loop, but if your goal is to get the name of the column between those indicates where the value is minimum, this line alone is enough:

```
df['BestP_Amin'] = df[['Bra','Nah','Tec','Ryc','Hla']].idxmin(axis=1)
```

No need to put it inside a `for` loop with those `if` statements. `idxmin` already performs a vectorized search for each row, producing the column as a result.
After this, the column looks like:

```
0    Nah
1    Nah
2    Bra
3    Bra
4    Bra
5    Bra
6    Bra
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, loop "For" must be used to "If". Need testing value in "BestP_A" and change choice for fill "BestP_Amin"

Answer (score 0):

Solved, use tuple

```
for i in range(0,len(data.index)):
    ...
    ...
    if data.at[i,'BestP_A'] == 'Bra':
        polemin = [data.loc[i,'Bra'],data.loc[i,'Nah'],data.loc[i,'Tec'],data.loc[i,'Ryc'],data.loc[i,'Hla']]
        data.at[i,'BestP_Min'] = min(polemin)
        data.at[i,'BestP_Idx'] = polemin.index(min(polemin))
    elif data.at[i,'BestP_A'] == 'Obr':
        polemin = [data.loc[i,'Obr'],data.loc[i,'Nah']...
```